# $scopeProvider <- $scope/ Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I testing my angular-application with jasmine(http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/) and getting next error: 
Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
I know, that it's incorrect to build dependency with scope in filters, services, factories, etc., but I use $scope in controller!
Why am i getting this error? controller looks like

```
testModule.controller('TestCont', ['$filter', '$scope', function($filter, $scope){

        var doPrivateShit = function(){
            console.log(10);
        };

        this.lol = function(){
            doPrivateShit();
        };

        this.add = function(a, b){
            return a+b;
        };

        this.upper = function(a){
            return $filter('uppercase')(a);
        }   

        $scope.a = this.add(1,2);

        $scope.test = 10;

        $scope.search = {

        };
    }]);
```

and my test's code:

```
'use strict';

describe('testModule module', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('testModule');
    });

    it('should uppercase correctly', inject(function($controller){
        var testCont = $controller('TestCont');
        expect(testCont.upper('lol')).toEqual('LOL');
        expect(testCont.upper('jumpEr')).toEqual('JUMPER');
        expect(testCont.upper('123azaza')).toEqual('123AZAZA');
        expect(testCont.upper('111')).toEqual('111');
    }));
});
```

Comment: Your syntax in your controller is correct. Most likely you are referencing $scope in a directive or service, which is incorrect.

Comment: Try this syntax:
    angular.module('yourAppName').controller('TestCont'

Comment: @PSL  
i edit my question and add code of test to it.

Answer (score 34):

You need to manually pass in a `$scope` to your controller:

```
describe('testModule module', function() {
    beforeEach(module('testModule'));

    describe('test controller', function() {
        var scope, testCont;

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            testCont = $controller('TestCont', {$scope: scope});
        }));

        it('should uppercase correctly', function() {
            expect(testCont.upper('lol')).toEqual('LOL');
            expect(testCont.upper('jumpEr')).toEqual('JUMPER');
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: But what if you want to test the $scope of the controller?

Comment: @Guy the scope you are passing in and the controller's scope are the same object. Since it's declared outside of the `beforeEach`, it is available in the `it`. Any changes made to the scope object in the controller will be present in the test.

Comment: So what is the meaning of this line:
scope = $rootScope.$new();

Comment: @Guy create a new child scope on the root scope and assign it to the variable `scope`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a $scope will be available as an injectable param only when the controller is attached to the DOM.

You need to associate somehow the controller to the DOM (I'm mot familiar with jasmine at all).

Answer (score 0):

I am following a video tutorial from egghead (link bellow) which suggest this approach:

```
describe("hello world", function () {
    var appCtrl;
    beforeEach(module("app"))
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
        appCtrl = $controller("AppCtrl");
    }))

    describe("AppCtrl", function () {
        it("should have a message of hello", function () {
            expect(appCtrl.message).toBe("Hello")
        })
    })
})
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl",  function () {
    this.message = "Hello";
});
```

I am posting it because in the answer selected we are creating a new scope. This means we cannot test the controller's scope vars, no?

link to video tutorial (1min) :
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-testing-a-controller

Comment: In your example you don't have any scope variables. If you inject `$scope` into your controller, your test will fail with OP's error message. If your controller requires a scope, you must manually inject it in your test harness. See https://gist.github.com/Swoogan/98017f256edd37d49f42 for an example of testing scope variables.