# Angular JS: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my app, but I'm running into an issue where I'm getting this error:

> Chrome 46.0.2490 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) app.customer "before each" hook for "should be created successfully" FAILED
>       Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- Customer

My `test.js` file looks like this:

```
describe('app.customers', function() {
  var controller;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app', function($provide) {});
    specHelper.injector(function($controller, $q, $rootScope, DataService) {});
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(DataService, 'getCustomers', function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(mockData.getMockCustomers());
      return deferred.promise;
    });

    controller = $controller('Customer');
    $rootScope.$apply();
  });

  describe('Customer Controller', function() {
    it('should be created successfully', function() {
      expect(controller).to.be.defined;
    });
  });

  specHelper.verifyNoOutstandingHttpRequests();
});
```

I'm not sure why it's looking for `$scopeProvider` as I'm not referencing `$scope.provider` in my test.

I'm pretty new to unit testing in general, so any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$scopeProvider <- $scope/ Unknown provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591402/scopeprovider-scope-unknown-provider)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize controller with a local scope.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(DataService, 'getCustomers', function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(mockData.getMockCustomers());
      return deferred.promise;
    });

    // inject local scope into controller
    controller = $controller('Customer', {$scope: $rootScope});
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

My guess is that your Customer controller is requiring $scope, but nothing is providing it. This is done for you automatically when running in an app, but something you need to provide manually when unit testing through $controller.

Comment: Hmm, now the error has changed to: `Error: Unexpected request: GET views/login.html
 No more request expected`. Again this path isn't referenced in my Customer controller but in my routing file.

Comment: Well your question was surrounding unknown provider $rootScopeProvider, which I gave you the solution for... I'm wondering if you should remove your specHelper.verifyNoOutstandingHttpRequest() for now since I'm not sure what that is doing.

Comment: Hmm, should I create another question that covers this issue? Removing `specHelper.verifyNoOutstandingHttpRequest()` makes no difference to the error I'm receiving.

Comment: If you post another question, I would suggest adding more of your code, perhaps controller and even what specHelper is. I think there is some $httpBackend stuff happening where it is expecting no outstanding requests, but your module config for routing is making a request to views/login.html -- still think this is driven through specHelper somehow, but again -- don't know what that's doing.